# Single color for each line in three.js

Tags: three.js, x3d

Is it possible to draw a line in three.js with a single color attribute, something similar to x3d's indexedLineSet than defining a color per vertex?

```
let material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xff0000,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `LineSegments` and the respective geometry object. There is no line material option that could replace such a color definition.

```js
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

var vertices = [];
var colors = [];

// geometry data for three line segments with different colors

vertices.push( 0, 0, 0 );
vertices.push( 1, 0, 0 );

vertices.push( 1, 0, 0 );
vertices.push( 1, 1, 0 );

vertices.push( 1, 1, 0 );
vertices.push( 0, 1, 0 );

colors.push( 1, 0, 0 );
colors.push( 1, 0, 0 );

colors.push( 0, 1, 0 );
colors.push( 0, 1, 0 );

colors.push( 0, 0, 1 );
colors.push( 0, 0, 1 );

geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

var lines = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );
scene.add( lines );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fLgvcka7/

`three.js R109`

Comment: x3d's indexedLineSet has a boolean attribute "colorPerVertex" which when is false you define a single color per line. In three.js you have to define two colors for a line i.e. start and end vertex.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you will see an interpolation effect. There is no way around if you want to achieve the intended effect.